# Passing a function as a parameter to class member function

Tags: c++, class, random, static-members, std-function

I am trying to add a random number generator functionality to my class and I want to do this as efficiently and succinctly as possible. I am using this class for a numerical simulation, thus I am using the mersenne_twister_engine, `std::mt19937`. The only way I have been able to successfully implemented this so far has been to define the random number generator within each member function that requires random number functionality. This solution seems less than optimal however. For example, in the .cpp file the function definition would be:

```
void SomeClass::RandomNumberFunction(){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> DIS;
    // Generate random number:
    float n = DIS(gen);

    ~~ some code using n ~~

}
```

The speed and memory usage of my program isn't of significance for my purposes, but I would like to know if there is some way in c++ of implement the mersenne_twister_engine and distribution more efficiently. In particular, one implementation which seems feasible is to pass pointers to the std::uniform_real_distribution<> and std::mt19937 objects to each member function that needs a random number, and these objects can be defined in the main() body. Or better, a std::bind object could be defined and a pointer to this passed to the relevant functions.

This doesn't seem like a massive improvement though upon my current implementation however.

What would be ideal, would be for the std::random_device, std::mt19937 and std::uniform_real_distribution<> objects to be members of the class. I have tried implementing this as:

SomeClass.h file:

```
class SomeClass(){
private:
    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 generator(rd()); 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(0.0, 1.0); 

public:
   SomeClass();
   ~SomeClass();
   void RandomNumberFunction();
}
```

SomeClass.cpp file:

```
void SomeClass::RandomNumberFunction(){

    float n = distribution(generator);

    ~~ some code using n ~~

}
```

But this isn't working- I can see that the putting the definitions of the distribution in the declaration of the function is what is causing the error, but I can't see the work around.

Is what I am trying to do possible, and if so is it even necessary? Is it worth my time trying to make the implementation more neat like this, or is the initial solution sufficient in practice?

Comment: Drop the initializer: `std::mt19937 generator;`. Instead, initialize in the constructor: `SomeClass::SomeClass() : generator(rd()) {}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, I see- thank you. Additionally, I'm not entirely clear about where the random device is initialised- is it simply initialised when you call it's operator() for the first time in the initialisation of generator?

Comment: It's initialized as part of class construction. You could write `SomeClass::SomeClass() : rd{}, generator(rd()) {}` to make it explicit; it's just that the initialization by default constructor can be omitted.

Comment: @cigien "Could" should be "should'. Any PRNG should only be seeded once for optimal behavior.

Comment: @sweenish fair enough, I deleted the comment.